# Regex to allow number within a range and strings from a set

Tags: python, regex

I have a range `[0..63]` and a python dict which maps string to values

```
# dscp name to value map
dscpAclMap = {
   "AF11": 10, "AF12": 12, "AF13": 14,
   "AF21": 18, "AF22": 20, "AF23": 22,
   "AF31": 26, "AF32": 28, "AF33": 30,
   "AF41": 34, "AF42": 36, "AF43": 38,
   "CS0": 0, "CS1": 8, "CS2": 16, "CS3": 24,
   "CS4": 32, "CS5": 40, "CS6": 48, "CS7": 56
   }
```

I would like to have a regex which allows only numbers from 0 to 63 and strings which are keys of `dscpAclMap`. I tried a quite a few things but nothing worked out.

P.S: I am pretty new to regex

Comment: Why use regex? Can you show the steps you took to get to this conclusion? It would be great if you could include some more of your code, sample input/output any errors/stacktrace you are getting.. Make sure you aren't falling into the dreaded [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and consult [ASK]. As it is, it is very hard to answer your question - you should look at some of the other regular expression questions and see that data is usually supplied so that we can actually give you a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t use regular expressions for this. Something like this is just fine:

```
value = "something"
if (value.isdigit() and 0 <= int(value) < 64) or value in dscpAclMap.keys():
    print('The value is valid.')
```

Answer (score 1):

For your curiosity, here is the regex for allowing only numbers from 0 to 63:

```
^(?:\d(?!\d)|[1-5]\d|6[0-3])$
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/kR4uF6

Comment: How did you generate that graph?

Comment: TIL http://www.debuggex.com and http://regex101.com – Those fancy tools might come in handy, thanks Alex :)

Comment: @thefourtheye I used http://debuggex.com